# How can I catch event from InputStream?

Tags: java, sockets, client

This is a client part of programm.
I have such class which works with sockets and has methods to read and write to server
How can I make an event to catch messages from server?
Some actionListener which makes actions only when thereis a message in inputStream.
I've tried timer which calls Running.receiveLine(); but it works very bad. 
The solution with while(true) also seems to be not good.

```
public class Running extends Thread{
private Socket s;
private PrintStream ps;
private BufferedReader br;

public Running(){
try{
    s = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 8072);
    ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
} catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
    System.out.println("11");
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("00");
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

public String receiveLine(){
    String ret = "";
    try {
        ret = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}

public void sendLine(String s){
    ps.println(s);
}

public void close(){
    try {
        s.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  }
```

Comment: y well you probably want while(true). What's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know how to connect it with to Swing interface.

Comment: Just to inform you... You are extending java.lang.Thread but you are not using it right. In this case, you receive no benefit from extending java.lang.Thread. If you want to, you should implement the run() method and then call the threads start() method.

Comment: when you say it's bad, what do you mean? Is it slow? or it doesn't return correct value or?

Comment: The timer is really bad solution. It works only during the frist opening of the frame. When I close it and open again the frame stopps reacting to timer's commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not a problem to use method `read()` because it blocks flow until new portion of data is available. All standard Java input streams have a good implementation of this approach, based on monitors. So your thread won't eat CPU and other resources during waiting.

Also you can refer to non-blocking IO in Java NIO.

**Small addition.**
To use it with `Swing` you can use queue approach in fusion with `SwingWorker`.